# Accessing controls from separate pages in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

In my MainWindow, I have a Frame control that holds Page1. Page1 contains a ComboBox. How do I add items to the ComboBox from MainWindow? I have tried this:

```
public MainWindow()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  Page1 page = new Page1(this);
  page.myComboBox.Items.Add("Test");
}
```

and in my page:

```
private MainWindow parent;

public Page1()
{
  InitializeComponent();
}

public Page1(MainWindow main)
{
  this.parent = main;
  InitializeComponent();
}
```

I have also tried setting x:FieldModifier="public" for both the ComboBox and the Frame control.

Comment: How do you show/display/navigate to `Page1` in `MainWindow`?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: You didn't post your whole code and I'm not sure if you are adding `Page1` to `MainWindow` as the Page has to be displayed inside the Window. I don't see something like `this.AddChild(page);` inside the `ctor` of `MainWindow`

Comment: Are you getting errors or is it just not adding the specified item?

Comment: It wasn't adding the specified item to myComboBox. I think I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I was initializing a new page and then never referencing it. If I navigate to page using `MyFrame.Navigate(page)` after `page.myComboBox.Items.Add("Test");` it updates the frame to the new page.